# Custom treeview VB.net

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I'm looking to create a custom treeview control in VB.net, what I need to do is have a standard treeview control displaying the system file strucure for example, but with an extra icon on the right on the folder/file name that only appears on hover over of the node. So, for instance, if I hover over the folder Sup2 as shown in the pic, then the orange icon appears

[image: Example]

I've done some research and from what I can see, I have to override the onpaint event to make this happen but I'm not sure exactly how to do this. I also need to add an onclick event to that new orange icon.

Comment: You can do that with a standard `TreeView` by setting the `DrawMode` to other than `Normal` and then handling the `DrawNode` event.  You can also create your own class that does the same internally, overriding `OnDrawNode` instead of handling the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following example will give you some hints and tips.

```vb
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Drawing.Text
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class TreeViewEx
    Inherits TreeView

#Region "API"

    Private Const TVM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE As Integer = &H1100 + 44
    Private Const TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER As Integer = &H4

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr,
                                        ByVal msg As Integer,
                                        ByVal wp As IntPtr,
                                        ByVal lp As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

#End Region

#Region "Private Fields"

    Private ReadOnly RightImage As Bitmap
    Private ReadOnly NSF As StringFormat

    Private HoverNode As TreeNode
    Private RightImageRect As Rectangle

#End Region

#Region "Constructors"

    Sub New()
        DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText
        RightImage = New Bitmap(My.Resources.Modify)
        NSF = New StringFormat With {
            .Alignment = StringAlignment.Near,
            .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
            .Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter,
            .FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoWrap
        }
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Paint"

    Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawNode(e As DrawTreeNodeEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnDrawNode(e)

        If e.Node Is Nothing Then Return

        Dim rect As Rectangle = e.Bounds : rect.Inflate(0, 1)

        If Not ClientRectangle.IntersectsWith(rect) Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim G As Graphics = e.Graphics

        G.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
        G.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit

        'Option1: If you want to draw different background color for the selected node.
        'If (e.State And TreeNodeStates.Selected) = TreeNodeStates.Selected Then
        '    Using br As New SolidBrush(Color.LightSteelBlue) '<- suit yourself!
        '        G.FillRectangle(br, rect)
        '    End Using
        'Else
        '    Using br As New SolidBrush(If(e.Node.BackColor.Equals(Color.Empty), BackColor, e.Node.BackColor))
        '        G.FillRectangle(br, rect)
        '    End Using
        'End If

        'Option2: If you don't want Option1.
        Using br As New SolidBrush(If(e.Node.BackColor.Equals(Color.Empty), BackColor, e.Node.BackColor))
            G.FillRectangle(br, rect)
        End Using

        Using br As New SolidBrush(If(e.Node.ForeColor.Equals(Color.Empty), ForeColor, e.Node.ForeColor))
            G.DrawString(e.Node.Text, If(e.Node.NodeFont, Font), br, rect, NSF)
        End Using

        If ReferenceEquals(e.Node, HoverNode) Then
            RightImageRect = New Rectangle(rect.Right + 5,
                                           rect.Y + ((rect.Height - RightImage.Height) / 2),
                                           rect.Height - 4, rect.Height - 4)
            G.DrawImage(RightImage,
                        RightImageRect,
                        New Rectangle(0, 0, RightImage.Width, RightImage.Height),
                        GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        End If
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Other Events"

    'You need this to reduce the flickering.
    Protected Overrides Sub OnHandleCreated(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        SendMessage(
            Handle,
            TVM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE,
            IntPtr.op_Explicit(TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER),
            IntPtr.op_Explicit(TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER)
            )
        MyBase.OnHandleCreated(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(e As MouseEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnMouseMove(e)

        Dim node = GetNodeAt(e.Location)

        If node IsNot Nothing Then
            'Avoid unnecessary Invalidate() calls.
            If Not ReferenceEquals(node, HoverNode) Then
                HoverNode = node
                Invalidate()
            End If
        Else
            'Avoid unnecessary Invalidate() calls.
            If HoverNode IsNot Nothing Then
                HoverNode = Nothing
                Invalidate()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(e As MouseEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnMouseDown(e)

        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left AndAlso
            RightImageRect.Contains(e.Location) Then
            'Notify the container to do something.
            OnEditButtonClicked()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseLeave(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnMouseLeave(e)
        Invalidate()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        If disposing Then
            RightImage.Dispose()
            NSF.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Custom Events"

    Public Class EditButtonClickArgs
        Inherits EventArgs

        Public Property Node As TreeNode

        Sub New(node As TreeNode)
            Me.Node = node
        End Sub
    End Class

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Raised when the right image is clicked.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Event EditButtonClicked As EventHandler(Of EditButtonClickArgs)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Raises the <see cref="EditButtonClicked"/> events.
    ''' </summary>
    Protected Overridable Sub OnEditButtonClicked()
        RaiseEvent EditButtonClicked(Me, New EditButtonClickArgs(HoverNode))
    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

In the Form that contains the new TreeViewEx control, you can handle the `EditButtonClicked` to do the necessary:

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Inherits Form

    Private Sub TreeViewEx1_EditButtonClicked(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEx.EditButtonClickArgs) Handles TreeViewEx1.EditButtonClicked
        'Do something with the e.Node
    End Sub

End Class
```

And here's a quick demo:

[image: TreeViewEx]

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is not professional but is worth giving a try..

I created a class that inherited from a `Treeview` control and overrode the constructor - changing the default width and height, setting the `DrawMode` to `TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText`.

Next, I handled the `TreeView.DrawNode` event, using a `PictureBox` to display the Image and changing its location based on the currently highlighted item.

I also handled the `Click` event of the `PictureBox`.Under that event, You can do whatever you want with the highlighted node.

I used images from `My.Resources` for `ImageList.Images(0)` and `PictureBox.Image`

```
Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim trv As New MyTreeView
        trv.Nodes.Add("Suppliers")
        trv.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("Sup 1")
        trv.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("Sup 2")
        trv.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("Sup 3")
        trv.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("Sup 4")
        trv.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("Sup 5")
        Controls.Add(trv)
    End Sub
End Class

'Class Starts Here
Public Class MyTreeView
    Inherits TreeView
    WithEvents myImage As PictureBox
    Dim activeItem As TreeNode    'Variable to store active TreeNode
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()              'Call the base class constructor
        'And set some values
        Height = 300
        Width = 300
        Location = New Point(50, 50)
        DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText       'Very neccesary
        AddHandler DrawNode, AddressOf MyTreeViewDrawNode   
        'Add event handlers
        AddHandler AfterCollapse, AddressOf MyTreeViewCollapsed
        'Set HotTracking event to true to allow for MouseHover
        HotTracking = True
        ImageList = new ImageList
        ImageList.Images.Add(My.Resources.FolderImage)
        ImageIndex = 0

        Font = New Font(Font.FontFamily, 10)
        'Initialize picturebox
        myImage = New PictureBox() With
        {
            .Image = My.Resources.editPencilImage,
            .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
            .Size = New Size(10, 10),
            .Visible = False
        }
        Controls.Add(myImage)
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyTreeViewCollapsed(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs)
        myImage.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Sub ImageClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles myImage.Click
        If (Not activeItem Is Nothing) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Clicked Item - " & activeItem.Text)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyTreeViewDrawNode(sender As Object, e As DrawTreeNodeEventArgs)
        e.DrawDefault = True
        If (e.State = TreeNodeStates.Hot) Then
            myImage.Visible = True
            activeItem = e.Node
            Dim tmpSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Node.Text, Font)
            myImage.Location = New Point(e.Node.Bounds.Location.X + tmpSize.Width, e.Node.Bounds.Location.Y)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]